# Distribution of nutrients throuought a drink made of plants?

Tags: human-biology, nutrition, botany, vitamins

In an attempts to eat my veggies for the day in one shot, I blended together a bag of salad with some water. The mixture separated by density, a thick top layer containing the bits of leaves, and a bottom layer of just juice. My question is: how many vitamins and nutrients are actually found in the top layer compared to the bottom, and how efficiently would the body process them?

Comment: I removed the sentence about you throwing up in case this appears to be a personal medical question to some people. I don't think it really is myself.

Comment: @dd3 that's ok I still got a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the drink was very well blended most of the water-soluble vitamis (B and C) as well sugars could dissolve in the juice. Fiber would mostly remain in the plant debris. Oils and fat-soluble vitamins (A, D, E, K) would form their own oily layer or be found in an emulsion with the fruit juice.